# here.com mapmarker setTitle not showing on the map

Tags: android, here-api

MapMarker code

```
// Create a custom marker image


   com.here.android.mpa.common.Image iconLocationMarker = new com.here.android.mpa.common.Image();
    try {
        iconLocationMarker.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pickuppoint_marker);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //finish();
    }
    // Create the MapMarker
    GeoCoordinate coordinate = new GeoCoordinate(lat,lng);
    MapMarker pickupMarker = new MapMarker(coordinate, iconLocationMarker);
    pickupMarker.setTitle("working " + name);

    map.addMapObject(pickupMarker);
```

in the above code **setTitle** is not showing on the map what's the problem in the code?. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the **showInfoWindow()** method of the Marker class.

**Note**: An info window allows you to display information to the user when they tap on a marker on a map. By default, an info window is displayed when a user taps on a marker if the marker has a title set. Only one info window is displayed at a time. If a user clicks on another marker, the current window will be hidden and the new info window will be displayed. You can show an info window programmatically by calling showInfoWindow() on the target marker. An info window can be hidden by calling hideInfoWindow().

Comment: I applied with pickupMarker.showInfoBubble(); it's not working but there is no showInfoWindow() with here.com map marker class.

Comment: Any error seen in logs when InfoBubble is not shown ?  To double check if the title is set correctly maybe try logging getTitle() ? Also showInfoBubble should be called after marker is added to map as mentioned in documentation, maybe that step is missing ? https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-mapping-mapmarker.html#topic-apiref__showinfobubble-void